# Записи с тремя разными шаблонами(WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress

Каким образом в WordPress вывести записи с разными шаблонами?

Есть внизу код, но он выводит записи только **по первому шаблону(Block-1).**

```js
<?php
global $post;

$myposts = get_posts([ 
'numberposts' => 3,
]);

if( $myposts ){
foreach( $myposts as $post ){
setup_postdata( $post );
?>

<div class ="Block-1 active">
<div class ="Content-left">
<h1 class="title-left"> <?php the_title(); ?> </h1>
<p class="Left_scroll">  <?php the_content(); ?> </p>
</div>
</div>

<?php }} wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

**А у меня три таких html-шаблона с разными именами классов дочерних элементов:**

```html
<div class ="Main_Block">


<div class ="Block-1 active">
<div class ="Content-left">
<h1 class="title-left"> Заголовок 1 </h1>
<p class="Left_scroll">
Контент(текст)-1
</p>
</div>
</div>


<div class ="Block-2">
<div class ="Content-right">
<h1 class="title-right"> Заголовок 2 </h1>
<p class="Right_scroll">
Контент(текст)-2
</p>
</div>
</div>


<div class ="Block-3">
<div class ="Content-center">
<h1 class="title-center"> Заголовок 3 </h1>
<p class="Center_scroll">
Контент(текст)-3
</p>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Всего должно получится 3 записи с тремя разными шаблонами,⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀  то есть сначала идет **Block-1 active > Block-2 > Block-3**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
global $post;

$my_posts = get_posts(
    [ 'numberposts' => 3 ]
);

$positions = [ 'Left', 'Right', 'Center' ];

if ( $my_posts ) {
    foreach ( $my_posts as $index => $my_post ) {
        setup_postdata( $my_post );
        ?>

        <div class="Block-<?php echo (int) $index + 1; ?> active">
            <div class="Content-<?php echo esc_attr( strtolower( $positions[ $index ] ) ); ?>">
                <h1 class="title-<?php echo esc_attr( strtolower( $positions[ $index ] ) ); ?>">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                </h1>
                <p class="<?php echo esc_attr( $positions[ $index ] ); ?>_scroll"><?php the_content(); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php
    }
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```